# Read URLs from .txt file Python

Tags: python, regex, url, pattern-matching

I am trying to extract URLs from a .txt file using regex (all the URLs end with .jpeg). This is my regex:

```
import re
output = re.findall('(http)(.*?)(jpeg)', text)
```

but my output looks like this:

```
('http', ://d1spq65clhrg1f.cloudfront.net/uploads/image_request/image/182/182382/182382534/cloudsight.', 'jpeg')
```

How can I avoid having the commas dividing the matches?

Comment: add sample data and output

Comment: Is it a requirement that you only capture URL's ending in ".jpeg"? Or are other endings also valid, e.g. ".jpg" or ".gif" or no extension at all? If so, can you make that clearer in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import re
output = re.findall('(http.*?jpeg)', text)
```

Output:

```
['http://d1spq65clhrg1f.cloudfront.net/uploads/image_request/image/182/182382/182382534/cloudsight.jpeg']
```

This will make "re.findall" to capture only one group - "http.*?jpeg", not three as in your regex.

Comment: Even the one group is unnecessary. `re.findall(r'http.*?jpeg', text)`.

Comment: Would you know where to point me for the bulk download of the images in the URLs?

Comment: @StefanoPozzi I've heard good things about search engines. You are hardly the first person in the world to use Python to download stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are looking for this

```
import re
output = " ".join(re.findall('(http)(.*?)(jpeg)', text))
```

Comment: I get this error: "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found"

Comment: It does not work, please don't answer if you are not sure.

Comment: @MunimMunna , i wasn't sure if op wanted to just remove comma and have it just as string. Nevertheless point duly noted. cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
import re 

with open("urls.txt") as f:
    urls = re.findall('(http*.*?jpeg)', f.read())
    print urls
```

Answer (score 0):

```
output = re.findall('https?:.*?.jpeg', text)
```

Example

```
import re
text=" asdd adf sdf sf http://d1spq65clhrg1f.cloudfront.net/uploads/image_request/image/182/182382/182382534/cloudsight.jpeg asfd ads f ads asdfadfasf asd asdf asdf asdf as"
output = re.findall('https?:.*?.jpeg', text)
print(output)
```

**Ouput:**

> ['http://d1spq65clhrg1f.cloudfront.net/uploads/image_request/image/182/182382/182382534/cloudsight.jpeg']